# Storing Custom Drawables in Array Causes Segmentation Error When Drawing Them

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, drawable, sfml

I have a `std::vector<Button>` called `levelButtons`which stores `Button`s like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        Button level(50, 50, std::bind(&Game::continueGame, this, (j * 8) + i), " " + std::to_string((j * 8) + i), &levelTexture);
        level.setPosition(50 + (i * 100), 200 + (j * 100));
        levelButtons.push_back(level);
    }
}
```

And then I draw them later like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<levelButtons.size(); i++) {
    win->draw(levelButtons[i]);
}
```

Where `win` is a `RenderWindow*`. The class Button looks like this:

```
Button::Button(float width, float height, std::function<void()> onclick, String face, Color fillColour) {
    arial.loadFromFile("/Users/mmysteriouss/Downloads/arial.ttf");
    pointerTexture.loadFromFile("/Users/mmysteriouss/Downloads/pointer.png");
    pointer.setTexture(pointerTexture);
    pointer.scale(0.04, 0.04);
    buttonface.setFont(arial);
    buttonface.setString(face);
    buttonface.setCharacterSize(30);
    buttonface.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    outline.setSize(Vector2f(width, height));
    outline.setOutlineColor(Color::Black);
    outline.setFillColor(fillColour);
    click = onclick;
}

Button::Button(float width, float height, std::function<void()> onclick, String face, Texture *fillTexture) {
    arial.loadFromFile("/Users/mmysteriouss/Downloads/arial.ttf");
    pointerTexture.loadFromFile("/Users/mmysteriouss/Downloads/pointer.png");
    pointer.setTexture(pointerTexture);
    pointer.scale(0.04, 0.04);
    buttonface.setFont(arial);
    buttonface.setString(face);
    buttonface.setCharacterSize(30);
    buttonface.setFillColor(Color::White);
    outline.setSize(Vector2f(width, height));
    outline.setOutlineColor(Color::Black);
    outline.setTexture(fillTexture);
    click = onclick;
}

void Button::handleClick(float x, float y) {
    if (outline.getGlobalBounds().contains(x, y)) {
        click();
    }
}

void Button::setPosition(float x, float y) {
    outline.setPosition(x, y);
    buttonface.setPosition(x, y);
}

void Button::handleMove(float x, float y) {
    hovering = outline.getGlobalBounds().contains(x, y);
    pointer.setPosition(x - 15, y - 5);
}
```

And it throws a

> Segmentation Fault: 11;

The report looks like this:

> thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> 0   libsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib     0x0000000107e0c6f7 sf::Font::setCurrentSize(unsigned int) const + 23
>
> 1   libsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib     0x0000000107e0c914 sf::Font::getUnderlinePosition(unsigned int) const + 30
>
> 2   libsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib     0x0000000107e35c30 sf::Text::ensureGeometryUpdate() const + 202
>
> 3   libsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib     0x0000000107e363aa sf::Text::draw(sf::RenderTarget&, sf::RenderStates) const + 38
>
> 4   libsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib     0x0000000107e29dfd sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&) + 41
>
> 5   light                          0x0000000107dcd081 Button::draw(sf::RenderTarget&, sf::RenderStates) const + 81 (Button.h:43)
>
> 6   libsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib     0x0000000107e29dfd sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&) + 41
>
> 7   light                          0x0000000107dd43c2 Game::draw() + 210 
>   (Game.cpp:26)
>
> 8   light                          0x0000000107dd4bc5 AbsGame::render() + 69 (AbsGame.h:44)
>
> 9   light                          0x0000000107dd4910 main + 496 (main.cpp:27)
>
> 10  libdyld.dylib                  0x00007fff76f58015 start + 1

Why does it throw a Segmentation Fault? I'm pretty sure my iteration is fine, and, my Button class works seperately - I created a main file to test it with and it worked...

Comment: if you are on linux try using valgrind to get more informations on the segfault

Comment: Which OS and IDE do you use?

Comment: @Tyker I am on mac + I used that report

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber Mac OS X High Sierra Netbeans IDE 8.2

Comment: @MBJH send the full report then

Comment: @Tyker there you go

Comment: seems the position was out of bounds and `i` starts with `1`?

Comment: @MBJH don't you have the line saying "invalid ... of size ... "

Comment: @Tyker I didn't see any line like that

Comment: @codekaizer It can't be out of bounds; the renderwindow is 1000x1000 and the button maximum goes out to 900,650

Comment: If the class works when you use it separately, maybe there is something wrong with the order you initialize your resources? In this case the `sf::Font` and the `sf::Text`.

Comment: what your Button class copy/move constructors look like? in your loop you create button on stack then move or copy it into vector and temporary object get deleted. if you dont have correct copy/move constructor problems will arise.

Comment: In line with @AndrewKashpur, try with `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back` and check if problem still there. It constructs the `Button` inside the vector, instead of construct and then move/copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I just simply added this code to load a sprite:

```
sf::Sprite Button::loadSprite(std::string source) {
    static sf::Texture t;
    t.loadFromFile(source);
    static sf::Sprite s;
    s.setTexture(t);
    return s;
}
```

and used it. Thanks for your help.